# How to get Zuul working with Spring Cloud Starter Parent 2020.05? Is it possible? Or am I forced to use Spring Cloud Gateway?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-cloud

Below I have pasted a snippet of the parent pom that the Zuul service is using. Zuul is utilizing the spring cloud starter parent 2020.0.5. Since Spring does not support Zuul after the Hoxton train release, I specified the version within the Zuul pom.

Parent Pom:

```
<dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>2020.0.5</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```

Zuul Service Pom:

```
<!-- ZUUL -->
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.10.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
        <!-- SPRING -->
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I tried doing this and it would not work.
What are my options if I want to keep Zuul?

Can I use later spring cloud versions (after Hoxton) with Zuul?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not possible. Zuul is no longer supported

Comment: @spencergibb So I have two options right? Either downgrade to a spring cloud parent version that supports Zuul or remove Zuul and implement Cloud Gateway

Comment: that is correct